# RemoteJMeterEngineImpl class in Jmeter, How to create instance and call rconfigure

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

#### Agenda -  Invoke JMeter of Remote Area from localhost Java class

I found that RemoteJMeterEngineImpl class helps to invoke JMeter of remote area

**Problem - Not able to create instance of RemoteJMeterEngineImpl  class due private constructor**

Please help if anybody knows how to play with RemoteJMeterEngineImpl  class

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something which is weird and definitely not supported. Normally you should have remote slaves up and running and if you need to kick off your test programatically I believe [DistributedRunner class](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/DistributedRunner.html) is something you could use.

Example code:

```
List<JMeterEngine> engines = new LinkedList<>();
Properties remoteProps = new Properties();
//set properties you want to send to remote clients here
DistributedRunner distributedRunner=new DistributedRunner(remoteProps);

List<String> hosts = new LinkedList<>();
//add your JMeter slaves here
hosts.add("remote_host_1");
hosts.add("remote_host_2");
distributedRunner.setStdout(System.out);
distributedRunner.setStdErr(System.err);
distributedRunner.init(hosts, testPlanTree);
engines.addAll(distributedRunner.getEngines());
distributedRunner.start();
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article and [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src) example project to learn more about programmatic creation and execution of JMeter tests.

Comment: Thank you, As i'm following mentioned steps i'm facing below exception. 
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
 java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 240, local class serialVersionUID = 241
Remote engines have been started

Comment: You need to use the same versions of JMeter on master and slaves

Comment: Both Machine JMeter versions (3.1) and JDK (jdk1.8.0_131) are same, still facing the exception. I'm able invoke this from command line successfully.  I would like to send class file if i get your email id

Comment: Do we need to configure anything on remote machine other than rmiregistry?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call

```
RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.startServer(rmiPort);
```

Code:

```
public static void startServer(int rmiPort) throws RemoteException {
        RemoteJMeterEngineImpl engine = new RemoteJMeterEngineImpl(DEFAULT_LOCAL_PORT, rmiPort == 0 ? DEFAULT_RMI_PORT : rmiPort);
        engine.init();
    }
```